# RadWho not working

Tags: networking, radius, freeradius

radwho: Error reading /var/log/freeradius/radutmp: No such file or directory
What should I be doing?

```
FreeRADIUS Version 2.1.12, for host x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, built on Dec 16 2012 at 13:28:43

Copyright (C) 1999-2009 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors. 

There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A 

PARTICULAR PURPOSE. 

You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the 

GNU General Public License v2. 

Starting - reading configuration files ...

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/proxy.conf

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/clients.conf

including files in directory /etc/freeradius/modules/

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/sqlcounter_expire_on_login

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/attr_filter

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/soh

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/otp

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/dynamic_clients

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/perl

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/etc_group

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/ntlm_auth

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/preprocess

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/detail.example.com

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/detail.log

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/krb5

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/ippool

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/opendirectory

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/redis

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/pap

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/detail

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/replicate

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/exec

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/linelog

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/logintime

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/unix

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/expiration

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/inner-eap

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/always

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/realm

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/radutmp

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/policy

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/digest

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/mac2vlan

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/mac2ip

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/smbpasswd

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/echo

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/pam

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/rediswho

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/files

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/ldap

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/chap

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/cui

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/checkval

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/counter

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/attr_rewrite

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/wimax

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/mschap

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/acct_unique

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/sql_log

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/sradutmp

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/expr

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/passwd

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/modules/smsotp

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/eap.conf

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/sql.conf

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/sql/mysql/dialup.conf

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/policy.conf

including files in directory /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default

including configuration file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel

main {

    user = "freerad"

    group = "freerad"

    allow_core_dumps = no

}

including dictionary file /etc/freeradius/dictionary

main {

    name = "freeradius"

    prefix = "/usr"

    localstatedir = "/var"

    sbindir = "/usr/sbin"

    logdir = "/var/log/freeradius"

    run_dir = "/var/run/freeradius"

    libdir = "/usr/lib/freeradius"

    radacctdir = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct"

    hostname_lookups = no

    max_request_time = 30

    cleanup_delay = 5

    max_requests = 1024

    pidfile = "/var/run/freeradius/freeradius.pid"

    checkrad = "/usr/sbin/checkrad"

    debug_level = 0

    proxy_requests = yes

 log {

    stripped_names = no

    auth = no

    auth_badpass = no

    auth_goodpass = no

 }

 security {

    max_attributes = 200

    reject_delay = 1

    status_server = yes

 }

}

radiusd: #### Loading Realms and Home Servers ####

 proxy server {

    retry_delay = 5

    retry_count = 3

    default_fallback = no

    dead_time = 120

    wake_all_if_all_dead = no

 }

 home_server localhost {

    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1

    port = 1812

    type = "auth"

    secret = "testing123"

    src_ipaddr = "127.0.0.1"

    response_window = 20

    max_outstanding = 65536

    require_message_authenticator = yes

    zombie_period = 40

    status_check = "status-server"

    ping_interval = 30

    check_interval = 30

    num_answers_to_alive = 3

    num_pings_to_alive = 3

    revive_interval = 120

    status_check_timeout = 4

  coa {

    irt = 2

    mrt = 16

    mrc = 5

    mrd = 30

  }

 }

 home_server_pool my_auth_failover {

    type = fail-over

    home_server = localhost

 }

 realm example.com {

    auth_pool = my_auth_failover

 }

 realm LOCAL {

 }

radiusd: #### Loading Clients ####

 client localhost {

    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1

    require_message_authenticator = no

    secret = "testing123"

    nastype = "other"

 }

radiusd: #### Instantiating modules ####

 instantiate {

 Module: Linked to module rlm_exec

 Module: Instantiating module "exec" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/exec

  exec {

    wait = no

    input_pairs = "request"

    shell_escape = yes

  }

 Module: Linked to module rlm_expr

 Module: Instantiating module "expr" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/expr

 Module: Linked to module rlm_expiration

 Module: Instantiating module "expiration" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/expiration

  expiration {

    reply-message = "Password Has Expired  "

  }

 Module: Linked to module rlm_logintime

 Module: Instantiating module "logintime" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/logintime

  logintime {

    reply-message = "You are calling outside your allowed timespan  "

    minimum-timeout = 60

  }

 }

radiusd: #### Loading Virtual Servers ####

server { # from file /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf

 modules {

  Module: Creating Auth-Type = digest

  Module: Creating Post-Auth-Type = REJECT

 Module: Checking authenticate {...} for more modules to load

 Module: Linked to module rlm_pap

 Module: Instantiating module "pap" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/pap

  pap {

    encryption_scheme = "auto"

    auto_header = no

  }

 Module: Linked to module rlm_chap

 Module: Instantiating module "chap" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/chap

 Module: Linked to module rlm_mschap

 Module: Instantiating module "mschap" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/mschap

  mschap {

    use_mppe = yes

    require_encryption = no

    require_strong = no

    with_ntdomain_hack = no

    allow_retry = yes

  }

 Module: Linked to module rlm_digest

 Module: Instantiating module "digest" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/digest

 Module: Linked to module rlm_unix

 Module: Instantiating module "unix" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/unix

  unix {

    radwtmp = "/var/log/freeradius/radwtmp"

  }

 Module: Linked to module rlm_eap

 Module: Instantiating module "eap" from file /etc/freeradius/eap.conf

  eap {

    default_eap_type = "md5"

    timer_expire = 60

    ignore_unknown_eap_types = no

    cisco_accounting_username_bug = no

    max_sessions = 4096

  }

 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_md5

 Module: Instantiating eap-md5

 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_leap

 Module: Instantiating eap-leap

 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_gtc

 Module: Instantiating eap-gtc

   gtc {

    challenge = "Password: "

    auth_type = "PAP"

   }

 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_tls

 Module: Instantiating eap-tls

   tls {

    rsa_key_exchange = no

    dh_key_exchange = yes

    rsa_key_length = 512

    dh_key_length = 512

    verify_depth = 0

    CA_path = "/etc/freeradius/certs"

    pem_file_type = yes

    private_key_file = "/etc/freeradius/certs/server.key"

    certificate_file = "/etc/freeradius/certs/server.pem"

    CA_file = "/etc/freeradius/certs/ca.pem"

    private_key_password = "whatever"

    dh_file = "/etc/freeradius/certs/dh"

    random_file = "/dev/urandom"

    fragment_size = 1024

    include_length = yes

    check_crl = no

    cipher_list = "DEFAULT"

    make_cert_command = "/etc/freeradius/certs/bootstrap"

    ecdh_curve = "prime256v1"

    cache {

    enable = no

    lifetime = 24

    max_entries = 255

    }

    verify {

    }

    ocsp {

    enable = no

    override_cert_url = yes

    url = "http://127.0.0.1/ocsp/"

    }

   }

 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_ttls

 Module: Instantiating eap-ttls

   ttls {

    default_eap_type = "md5"

    copy_request_to_tunnel = no

    use_tunneled_reply = no

    virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"

    include_length = yes

   }

 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_peap

 Module: Instantiating eap-peap

   peap {

    default_eap_type = "mschapv2"

    copy_request_to_tunnel = no

    use_tunneled_reply = no

    proxy_tunneled_request_as_eap = yes

    virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"

    soh = no

   }

 Module: Linked to sub-module rlm_eap_mschapv2

 Module: Instantiating eap-mschapv2

   mschapv2 {

    with_ntdomain_hack = no

    send_error = no

   }

 Module: Checking authorize {...} for more modules to load

 Module: Linked to module rlm_preprocess

 Module: Instantiating module "preprocess" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/preprocess

  preprocess {

    huntgroups = "/etc/freeradius/huntgroups"

    hints = "/etc/freeradius/hints"

    with_ascend_hack = no

    ascend_channels_per_line = 23

    with_ntdomain_hack = no

    with_specialix_jetstream_hack = no

    with_cisco_vsa_hack = no

    with_alvarion_vsa_hack = no

  }

 Module: Linked to module rlm_realm

 Module: Instantiating module "suffix" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/realm

  realm suffix {

    format = "suffix"

    delimiter = "@"

    ignore_default = no

    ignore_null = no

  }

 Module: Linked to module rlm_files

 Module: Instantiating module "files" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/files

  files {

    usersfile = "/etc/freeradius/users"

    acctusersfile = "/etc/freeradius/acct_users"

    preproxy_usersfile = "/etc/freeradius/preproxy_users"

    compat = "no"

  }

 Module: Linked to module rlm_sql

 Module: Instantiating module "sql" from file /etc/freeradius/sql.conf

  sql {

    driver = "rlm_sql_mysql"

    server = "localhost"

    port = ""

    login = "radius"

    password = "radpass"

    radius_db = "radius"

    read_groups = yes

    sqltrace = no

    sqltracefile = "/var/log/freeradius/sqltrace.sql"

    readclients = no

    deletestalesessions = yes

    num_sql_socks = 5

    lifetime = 0

    max_queries = 0

    sql_user_name = "%{User-Name}"

    default_user_profile = ""

    nas_query = "SELECT id, nasname, shortname, type, secret, server FROM nas"

    authorize_check_query = "SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op           FROM radcheck           WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}'           ORDER BY id"

    authorize_reply_query = "SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op           FROM radreply           WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}'           ORDER BY id"

    authorize_group_check_query = "SELECT id, groupname, attribute,           Value, op           FROM radgroupcheck           WHERE groupname = '%{Sql-Group}'           ORDER BY id"

    authorize_group_reply_query = "SELECT id, groupname, attribute,           value, op           FROM radgroupreply           WHERE groupname = '%{Sql-Group}'           ORDER BY id"

    accounting_onoff_query = "          UPDATE radacct           SET              acctstoptime       =  '%S',              acctsessiontime    =  unix_timestamp('%S') -                                    unix_timestamp(acctstarttime),              acctterminatecause =  '%{Acct-Terminate-Cause}',              acctstopdelay      =  %{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0}           WHERE acctstoptime IS NULL           AND nasipaddress      =  '%{NAS-IP-Address}'           AND acctstarttime     <= '%S'"

    accounting_update_query = "           UPDATE radacct           SET              framedipaddress = '%{Framed-IP-Address}',              acctsessiontime     = '%{Acct-Session-Time}',              acctinputoctets     = '%{%{Acct-Input-Gigawords}:-0}'  << 32 |                                    '%{%{Acct-Input-Octets}:-0}',              acctoutputoctets    = '%{%{Acct-Output-Gigawords}:-0}' << 32 |                                    '%{%{Acct-Output-Octets}:-0}'           WHERE acctsessionid = '%{Acct-Session-Id}'           AND username        = '%{SQL-User-Name}'           AND nasipaddress    = '%{NAS-IP-Address}'"

    accounting_update_query_alt = "           INSERT INTO radacct             (acctsessionid,    acctuniqueid,      username,              realm,            nasipaddress,      nasportid,              nasporttype,      acctstarttime,     acctsessiontime,              acctauthentic,    connectinfo_start, acctinputoctets,              acctoutputoctets, calledstationid,   callingstationid,              servicetype,      framedprotocol,    framedipaddress,              acctstartdelay,   xascendsessionsvrkey)           VALUES             ('%{Acct-Session-Id}', '%{Acct-Unique-Session-Id}',              '%{SQL-User-Name}',              '%{Realm}', '%{NAS-IP-Address}', '%{NAS-Port}',              '%{NAS-Port-Type}',              DATE_SUB('%S',                       INTERVAL (%{%{Acct-Session-Time}:-0} +                                 %{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0}) SECOND),                       '%{Acct-Session-Time}',              '%{Acct-Authentic}', '',              '%{%{Acct-Input-Gigawords}:-0}' << 32 |              '%{%{Acct-Input-Octets}:-0}',              '%{%{Acct-Output-Gigawords}:-0}' << 32 |              '%{%{Acct-Output-Octets}:-0}',              '%{Called-Station-Id}', '%{Calling-Station-Id}',              '%{Service-Type}', '%{Framed-Protocol}',              '%{Framed-IP-Address}',              '0', '%{X-Ascend-Session-Svr-Key}')"

    accounting_start_query = "           INSERT INTO radacct             (acctsessionid,    acctuniqueid,     username,              realm,            nasipaddress,     nasportid,              nasporttype,      acctstarttime,    acctstoptime,              acctsessiontime,  acctauthentic,    connectinfo_start,              connectinfo_stop, acctinputoctets,  acctoutputoctets,              calledstationid,  callingstationid, acctterminatecause,              servicetype,      framedprotocol,   framedipaddress,              acctstartdelay,   acctstopdelay,    xascendsessionsvrkey)           VALUES             ('%{Acct-Session-Id}', '%{Acct-Unique-Session-Id}',              '%{SQL-User-Name}',              '%{Realm}', '%{NAS-IP-Address}', '%{NAS-Port}',              '%{NAS-Port-Type}', '%S', NULL,              '0', '%{Acct-Authentic}', '%{Connect-Info}',              '', '0', '0',              '%{Called-Station-Id}', '%{Calling-Station-Id}', '',              '%{Service-Type}', '%{Framed-Protocol}', '%{Framed-IP-Address}',              '%{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0}', '0', '%{X-Ascend-Session-Svr-Key}')"

    accounting_start_query_alt = "           UPDATE radacct SET              acctstarttime     = '%S',              acctstartdelay    = '%{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0}',              connectinfo_start = '%{Connect-Info}'           WHERE acctsessionid  = '%{Acct-Session-Id}'           AND username         = '%{SQL-User-Name}'           AND nasipaddress     = '%{NAS-IP-Address}'"

    accounting_stop_query = "           UPDATE radacct SET              acctstoptime       = '%S',              acctsessiontime    = '%{Acct-Session-Time}',              acctinputoctets    = '%{%{Acct-Input-Gigawords}:-0}' << 32 |                                   '%{%{Acct-Input-Octets}:-0}',              acctoutputoctets   = '%{%{Acct-Output-Gigawords}:-0}' << 32 |                                   '%{%{Acct-Output-Octets}:-0}',              acctterminatecause = '%{Acct-Terminate-Cause}',              acctstopdelay      = '%{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0}',              connectinfo_stop   = '%{Connect-Info}'           WHERE acctsessionid   = '%{Acct-Session-Id}'           AND username          = '%{SQL-User-Name}'           AND nasipaddress      = '%{NAS-IP-Address}'"

    accounting_stop_query_alt = "           INSERT INTO radacct             (acctsessionid, acctuniqueid, username,              realm, nasipaddress, nasportid,              nasporttype, acctstarttime, acctstoptime,              acctsessiontime, acctauthentic, connectinfo_start,              connectinfo_stop, acctinputoctets, acctoutputoctets,              calledstationid, callingstationid, acctterminatecause,              servicetype, framedprotocol, framedipaddress,              acctstartdelay, acctstopdelay)           VALUES             ('%{Acct-Session-Id}', '%{Acct-Unique-Session-Id}',              '%{SQL-User-Name}',              '%{Realm}', '%{NAS-IP-Address}', '%{NAS-Port}',              '%{NAS-Port-Type}',              DATE_SUB('%S',                  INTERVAL (%{%{Acct-Session-Time}:-0} +                  %{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0}) SECOND),              '%S', '%{Acct-Session-Time}', '%{Acct-Authentic}', '',              '%{Connect-Info}',              '%{%{Acct-Input-Gigawords}:-0}' << 32 |              '%{%{Acct-Input-Octets}:-0}',              '%{%{Acct-Output-Gigawords}:-0}' << 32 |              '%{%{Acct-Output-Octets}:-0}',              '%{Called-Station-Id}', '%{Calling-Station-Id}',              '%{Acct-Terminate-Cause}',              '%{Service-Type}', '%{Framed-Protocol}', '%{Framed-IP-Address}',              '0', '%{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0}')"

    group_membership_query = "SELECT groupname           FROM radusergroup           WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}'           ORDER BY priority"

    connect_failure_retry_delay = 60

    simul_count_query = ""

    simul_verify_query = "SELECT radacctid, acctsessionid, username,                                nasipaddress, nasportid, framedipaddress,                                callingstationid, framedprotocol                                FROM radacct                                WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}'                                AND acctstoptime IS NULL"

    postauth_query = "INSERT INTO radpostauth                           (username, pass, reply, authdate)                           VALUES (                           '%{User-Name}',                           '%{%{User-Password}:-%{Chap-Password}}',                           '%{reply:Packet-Type}', '%S')"

    safe-characters = "@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.-_: /"

  }

rlm_sql (sql): Driver rlm_sql_mysql (module rlm_sql_mysql) loaded and linked

rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect to radius@localhost:/radius

rlm_sql (sql): starting 0

rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_mysql #0

rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server for #0

rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #0

rlm_sql (sql): starting 1

rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_mysql #1

rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server for #1

rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #1

rlm_sql (sql): starting 2

rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_mysql #2

rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server for #2

rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #2

rlm_sql (sql): starting 3

rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_mysql #3

rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server for #3

rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #3

rlm_sql (sql): starting 4

rlm_sql (sql): Attempting to connect rlm_sql_mysql #4

rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server for #4

rlm_sql (sql): Connected new DB handle, #4

 Module: Checking preacct {...} for more modules to load

 Module: Linked to module rlm_acct_unique

 Module: Instantiating module "acct_unique" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/acct_unique

  acct_unique {

    key = "User-Name, Acct-Session-Id, NAS-IP-Address, Client-IP-Address, NAS-Port"

  }

 Module: Checking accounting {...} for more modules to load

 Module: Linked to module rlm_detail

 Module: Instantiating module "detail" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/detail

  detail {

    detailfile = "/var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d"

    header = "%t"

    detailperm = 384

    dirperm = 493

    locking = no

    log_packet_header = no

  }

 Module: Linked to module rlm_radutmp

 Module: Instantiating module "radutmp" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/radutmp

  radutmp {

    filename = "/var/log/freeradius/radutmp"

    username = "%{User-Name}"

    case_sensitive = yes

    check_with_nas = yes

    perm = 384

    callerid = yes

  }

 Module: Linked to module rlm_attr_filter

 Module: Instantiating module "attr_filter.accounting_response" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/attr_filter

  attr_filter attr_filter.accounting_response {

    attrsfile = "/etc/freeradius/attrs.accounting_response"

    key = "%{User-Name}"

    relaxed = no

  }

 Module: Checking session {...} for more modules to load

 Module: Checking post-proxy {...} for more modules to load

 Module: Checking post-auth {...} for more modules to load

 Module: Instantiating module "attr_filter.access_reject" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/attr_filter

  attr_filter attr_filter.access_reject {

    attrsfile = "/etc/freeradius/attrs.access_reject"

    key = "%{User-Name}"

    relaxed = no

  }

 } # modules

} # server

server inner-tunnel { # from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel

 modules {

 Module: Checking authenticate {...} for more modules to load

 Module: Checking authorize {...} for more modules to load

 Module: Checking session {...} for more modules to load

 Module: Checking post-proxy {...} for more modules to load

 Module: Checking post-auth {...} for more modules to load

 } # modules

} # server

radiusd: #### Opening IP addresses and Ports ####

listen {

    type = "auth"

    ipaddr = *

    port = 0

}

listen {

    type = "acct"

    ipaddr = *

    port = 0

}

listen {

    type = "auth"

    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1

    port = 18120

}

 ... adding new socket proxy address 127.0.0.1 port 39513

Listening on authentication address * port 1812

Listening on accounting address * port 1813

Listening on authentication address 127.0.0.1 port 18120 as server inner-tunnel

Listening on proxy address * port 1814

Ready to process requests.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resason why despite being *`root`* you get the following error:

```
`radwho`: Error reading /var/log/radius/sradutmp: No such file or directory
```

The *`sradutmp`* file does not exist because the `sradutmp module` is disabled
inside the accounting section of the *`sites-enabled/default`* virtual
server. Activate `sradutmp` by uncommenting the following line:

```
#sradutmp
```

Then Restart the server in debugging mode:

```
/etc/init.d/freeradius stop
freeradius -X
```

Issue the `radclient` and `radwho`
commands as before. You should now see something like the following:

```
 #radwho     Login Name  What TTY When From Location<br>
 alice       alice       shell S0 Mon  04:20 127.0.0.1
```

PS:

### 1) RadClient Syntax:

```
radclient 127.0.0.1 auto testing123 -f 4088_06_acct_start.txt
```

### 2) 4088_06_acct_start.txt:

```
Packet-Type=4
Packet-Dst-Port=1813
Acct-Session-Id = "4D2BB8AC-00000098"
Acct-Status-Type = Start
Acct-Authentic = RADIUS
User-Name = "alice"
NAS-Port = 0
Called-Station-Id = "00-02-6F-AA-AA-AA:My Wireless"
Calling-Station-Id = "00-1C-B3-AA-AA-AA"
NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11
Connect-Info = "CONNECT 48Mbps 802.11b"
```

Answer (score 1):

That suggests that either the radutmp module isn't listen in the session section of your configuration, or you haven't received any accounting packets.

Run the server in debug mode `-X`, verify you're receiving accounting packets from your NAS, and that you've [listed the radutmp module](http://www.github.com/Freeradius/freeradius-server/blob/v2.x.x/raddb/sites-available/default#L450) in the session section.

Answer (score 1):

just a note that with version 3 (at least) you need to enable radutmp (sradutmp is the "secure radutmp" but radwho looks for radutmp

Answer (score -2):

Sufficient information should be given while sending accounting requests to the server. Just add `NAS-Port` and `NAS-IP-Address` while sending the request. Then call `radwho`. It will definitely work.